# Find Dates Before Specified Date and Insert Them Using PHP & SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a date outputted from the database:

```
$deadline = $row['DEADLINE'];
```

When I print $deadline it returns: 2015-05-03 18:00:00

Now I want a way to find each day 24 hours before up until todays date and then use each of those values to insert in a new table in the database.

So in this case I want:

```
2015-05-03 18:00:00
2015-05-02 18:00:00
2015-05-01 18:00:00
2015-04-30 18:00:00
2015-04-29 18:00:00
```

To be inserted into the database 5 new rows.  So I know I need todays date:

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

Then I have the date of the deadline:

```
$deadline = $row['DEADLINE'];
```

I can then find the difference in days:

```
$dateDiff = ($deadline - $now)/(24*60*60);
```

This gives me a figure (in this case it will be 5).  Then could I use this figure to display the date and time for 5 days prior?

Not sure how I would insert them all though. Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: So your end result what you want would be the range between today and the date from the db, *right* ? Also have you tried something ?

Comment: Yes I need the 5 dates listed. to be inserted into a table and I'm not sure firstly how to get those 5 dates and secondly how to insert them as I would need a loop in there to insert each of the 5 dates in new rows.

Comment: @andy Have you tired something? Show us your code/attempts!

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/fr/class.datetime.php) object, really easiest way :

PHP :

```
$now = new datetime();
$sub = new datetime();

for($i=0;$i<5;$i++)
{
    $sub->sub(new DateInterval('P1D'));

    echo $sub->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br />';
    echo $sub->diff($now)->format('%a days').'<br />';


}
```

OUTPUT :

```
2015-04-29 14:18:09
1 days
2015-04-28 14:18:09
2 days
2015-04-27 14:18:09
3 days
2015-04-26 14:18:09
4 days
2015-04-25 14:18:09
5 days
```

Comment: This just goes through 5 days, if OP just changes the dates by 2 days or so this code breaks!

Comment: I agree with you to use a Object like DateTime, or Carbon/Carbon

Answer (score 0):

This isent perfect, but it will probably get you started

Try Using Datetime http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Or Carbon/Carbon Package: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

```
$datetime = new DateTime("2015-04-03 18:00:00");
$now = new DateTime('NOW');

$difference = $datetime->diff($now);

echo '<pre>';

for($i = 1; $i <= $difference->days; $i++)
{

    if($difference->invert){
        var_dump (
            $temp = $datetime
            ->modify('-1 day')
            ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
    }else{

        var_dump (
            $temp = $datetime
                ->modify('+1 day')
                ->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
        );
    }
}
```